# How can I narrow down a return type to a more specific type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript

This came up when working with the mysql2/promise library in TypeScript.

Consider the following (abbreviated) Snippet:

```js
import {FieldPacket, PoolConnection, RowDataPacket} from 'mysql2/promise';

let connection: PoolConnection = await promisePool.getConnection();

connection.query(FETCH_USER_ID)//returns Promise<[(RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader), FieldPacket[]]>
    .then((results: [RowDataPacket,FieldPacket[]]) => {
        fields.UserID = results[0].value;
    });
```

From the semantics of my query, I know for a fact that in this specific case the return type will indeed be `[RowDataPacket,FieldPacket[]]`, but TypeScript does not allow that assignment because it is of course formally wrong.

The case where formally a number of types *could* apply, but semantically only one of them or a subset thereof are possible in any given situation can't be that rare, so I assume there must be a solution.

How can I tell TypeScript to expect a subset of the theoretically possible types, preferably without resorting to any or ts-ignore?

Comment: You can try `as [RowDataPacket,FieldPacket[]]` to narrow the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type cast the result using the `as` operator.

```
import {FieldPacket, PoolConnection, RowDataPacket} from 'mysql2/promise';

let connection: PoolConnection = await promisePool.getConnection();

connection.query(FETCH_USER_ID)//returns Promise<[(RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader), FieldPacket[]]>
    .then((res) => {
        const results = res as [RowDataPacket,FieldPacket[]]
        fields.UserID = results[0].value;
    });
```

Comment: I suppose that `as unknown` is not needed, since this is a legit narrowing and we are not forcing it

Comment: Yeah, fair enough.

Comment: Thank you @Mark, that was exactly what I was looking for.